# Running Apache without explicitly declaring listening on ports such as :3000 or :6600

Tags: ruby, apache2

Using Ruby and Thin as a web service.  Apache is also loaded.  Can't access the web service because listing ports, such as `:3000` or `:6600`, in the GET url is not allowed.  How is the port requirement removed?

Answer (score 1):

Use Apache ProxyPass.

cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
sudo vi 000-default

Edit Lines:

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ProxyPass /breakfast http://localhost:4567/breakfast
    DocumentRoot /var/www

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about Apache HTTPD, either leave off the port, or specify "80" for the port.

If you're talking about Apache Tomcat, you'll need to set up an HTTP Connector with port=80, but Tomcat will need to be launched as root.